# I'm trying to round a image and the top of the circle isn't rounding. I believe it's due to a padding issue but I need the padding for spacing

Tags: html, css

[problem photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTXvY.jpg)

I'm trying to make this image a circle I believe I might have too much padding. When I adjust the border-radius it doesn't round correctly. I have added the html and a link to see the problem.

```
button 
    { 
    background-color: #433966;
    border: 5px solid #5d596a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(65, 62, 62, 0.2);
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    color: rgb(205, 187, 162);
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Optima;

    }

 img 
    {
     border-radius: 50%;
     perspective: 8px;
     padding-bottom:5%;
     padding-top: 20%;
     border-color: silver;
     width: 300px !important;
     height: 300px !important;
    }
  <div class="fade-in-image">
        <img src="images/rachel.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="center"
        width= 100%>
        
        <button>Portfolio</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your html code

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - it is much easier for us to help without guessing if we have a definite example to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your image in another element and add padding and other styles to it

```css
div 
    {
     border-radius: 20%;
     perspective: 8px;
     padding-bottom:5%;
     padding-top: 20%;
     border-color: silver;
     width: 300px !important;
     height: 300px !important;
    }

div img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a margin instead of padding to add space and it will work fine

```
 img 
{
 border-radius: 20%;
 perspective: 8px;
 margin-bottom:5%;
 margin-top: 20%;
 border-color: silver;
 width: 300px !important;
 height: 300px !important;
}
```

[image for padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1qHV.png)
vs
[image for margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQqpf.png)